# como puedo hacer para buscar en algunas columnas y no en todasdatatables js?

Tags: php, datatable

Esto usando Datatables JS, este seria el codigo para usar el datatable. todo funciona bien pero quiero hacer que la busqueda solo se genere en 2 columnas y no en todas

```
  
$('#datatables').DataTable({
          "language": {
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
          },
          "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
          "responsive": false,
          "autoWidth": true,
          "searching": true,
          "length": true,
          "select": true,
          dom: 'lBfrtip',
          buttons: {
            buttons: [
              'excel'
            ]

          }
       });
```

esta seria la tabla que se genera

```
                $inf.='<tr>';
                    $inf.='<th>#</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Productos</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Existencia</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Categoría</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Precio de Compra</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Precio de Venta</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Porcentaje de Garantía</th>';
                    $inf.='<th>Gestión</th>';
                $inf.='</tr>';
```

pero solo quiero buscar en producto y en la categoria... Sucede que si coloco "22" en la busqueda tambien salta lo relacionado con los precios...

Alguna idea para mejorar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy fácil, copia y pega este arreglo de objetos tal cual como una propiedad en la parte donde declaras las propiedades de tu datatables. Esto impedira que se busque y se muestre dichas columnas indicadas

```
 columnDefs: [{
        "targets": [0,1,2], //definimos las columnas
        "visible": false, // se van ocultar
        "searchable": false //bloquea su busqueda
    }]
```

Comment: Te recomiendo dejar los comentarios y una explicación de tu script fuera del código. decir que muy fácil no aporta nada a la explicación, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Agrega lo siguiente la opción -> searchBuilder. según el indice de la columna a considerar en la busqueda

mas info en https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchBuilder.columns

```
searchBuilder: {
        columns: [1,2]
    },
```

Ejemplo:

```
$('#datatables').DataTable({
          "language": {
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
          },
          "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
          "responsive": false,
          "autoWidth": true,
          "searching": true,
          "length": true,
          "select": true,
    searchBuilder: {
        columns: [1,2]
    }, 
          dom: 'lBfrtip',
          buttons: {
            buttons: [
              'excel'
            ]

          },

       });
```

Comment: ya lo intente hacer, sin embargo sigue buscando en las tambien